# Forms authentication to create bearer tokens for Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication

We have a .NET web forms project using sql membership forms authentication which our website runs on. We're now trying to set up an Web API 2 project and would like users consuming the API to authenticate their calls to the API with their website credentials.

1. Do we have to update our website to Identity authentication? ...or
2. Is it possible for us to use our existing membership / forms authentication to authenticate a user, and then give them a token which they can use for subsequent calls?

In either scenario, how do I implement that scenario?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

1. No need to upgrade for ASP.NET Identity, you can work with membership provider
2. You can use your legacy membership provider to validate username and password, by looking at the code below you need to change the line of code prefixed with (**) with your memebership.validate user method and thats it.

You can read more about this in my detailed [Token based Authentication Post](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
        {
            **IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);**

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

        context.Validated(identity);

    }
```