# Migrating From .Net Forms Authentication to SPA With Tokens

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I have a legacy .net web forms website that is over 10 years old that I am in the process of modernizing into a single page app with React on the front and a .net7 api on the back.

The current website uses SqlMembershipProvider for authentication so all current user accounts and info are stored in the database and the .net forms app takes care of everything for me.

Since I am going for a SPA, I will need the users to get a token for authentication. I'll be honest, I am new to token based authentication so I am looking to understand what my options are. Ideally, I'd like there to be a seamless transition for current users. Moving account data isn't ideal as all passwords are hashed so if I have to go with an external provider, I feel like I'd have to force all users to do a reset password.

I did come across this post in my searching. The poster's setup sounds identical to mine, but is nearly 9 years old now and perhaps is out of date? [Forms authentication to create bearer tokens for Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042019/forms-authentication-to-create-bearer-tokens-for-web-api)

Is there a route I can take where the new api backend I am developing can perform the authenticating using the current aspnet_Membership_* tables?